# Create a curved face between two bezier curves in Blender 2.8

Tags: modeling, faces, bezier-curves

I'm trying to create a curved face between two curved edges. I've converted two parallel bezier curves to mesh
[image]
[image]

but when I switch to edit mode, select 4 of the vertices, and hit F it doesn't create a face.

[image]

Can anyone see what I'm missing? I'm very new to Blender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like each side is a separate mesh object (You have two white 'active' vertices, one for each mesh). If you select both in object mode you can join them into one using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd>.

Editing multiple meshes at the same time is a new feature in 2.8, and allows for many useful operations, but if they are separate objects, they still can't share any of their actual geometery.

Comment: Thank you so much!